# Get Offsets between two offsets in a canvas

Tags: flutter, canvas

am trying to get all the offsets between two offsets E.g Offset(173.0, 205.0) and  Offset(186.0, 358.0). i want to get the list of offsets and save them in a list. presently am using `canvas.drawLine(p1, p2, paint)` where p1 is `Offset(173.0, 205.0)` and p2 is `Offset(186.0, 358.0)`. When the line is drawn i want to be able to get all the offsets that make up that line

Comment: in theory there is infinite number of such offsets, in practice it is limited to the precision of the double datatype

Comment: @pskink what do you suggest i do

Comment: how many such offsets do you want?

Comment: @pskink enough to show a straight line, the problem is i cant say 10, 20 or 100. the user is supposed to select the start point and the end point, click a button and it draws a line. if i say 10 for instance. 10 will be able to draw a straight line for two points that are close, but it wont for two far points

Comment: i dont get you: if you want to draw a straight line use `canvas.drawLine` - do you really want to draw N points that form a line? do they have different color or something?

Comment: i need to be able to save the drawn line on the screen so the user can draw more lines or curves while still seeing the ones they have drawn. is like drawing a line on a piece of paper, after you draw that line, you may decide to draw another line on the same piece of paper. except there is another way of saving drawn lines instead of having to save the offsets that makes up the line @pskink

Comment: sorry i dont understand it at all, but if you still want those offsets use [Offset.lerp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Offset/lerp.html) static method (though i think its some kind of bad idea to get those offsets)